# How to get difference between two dates in all records using sql select query

Tags: sql-server, datetime

Let me explain what I want:
Suppose 100 records are in my table(column name:id,imei,latitude,longitude,datetime,status)

Then, I put 50 records with 10000001 imei number, now I have to get the records that have status 0 and date difference between more than 5 minutes with the same imei.

How do I get records with status 0 and time duration more then 5?

In sort I need to compare 1 date and 2 date then 2 date and 3 date then 3 date and 4 date then 4 date and 5 date, and so on.

Comment: please post some sample data as your question is quite unclear

Comment: id  imei_no      DateTime                            Latitude           Longitude
1  10000001   2015-11-23 18:57:16.000   28.4117555          74.9443555
2  10000001   2015-11-23 19:07:18.000   27.4117555          75.9443555
3  10000001   2015-11-23 19:17:20.000   28.4117555          75.9455555

Comment: id  imei_no      DateTime                            Latitude           Longitude
1  10000001   2015-11-23 18:57:16.000   28.4117555          74.9443555
2  10000001   2015-11-23 19:07:18.000   27.4117555          75.9443555
3  10000001   2015-11-23 19:17:20.000   28.4117555          75.9455555
4  10000001  2015-11-23 19:27:22.000   25.4117555          75.9443555

i need to compare id 1 datetime  and id 2 datetime then id 2 datetime and id 3 datetime and get the result

Answer (score 0):

this will group the imei and sort them by datetime then compare each datetime as it is in ascending order. since you haven't given any better way to sort them, i'll assume this is what you're looking for

```
; WITH T AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY imei ORDER BY datetime) RN
    FROM tblName)
SELECT T1.imei, T1.status, T1.datetime [date1], T2.datetime [date2], DATEDIFF(mi, T1.datetime, T2.datetime) [difference]
FROM T T1 
JOIN (SELECT imei, RN, datetime FROM T WHERE RN > 1) T2 ON T2.RN-1 = T1.RN AND T1.imei = T2.imei
WHERE T1.datetime < DATEADD(mm, -5, T2.datetime)
AND T1.Status = 0
```

Alternatively, if you want JUST the date differences (regardless of whether they're greater than or less than 5), you could do it like this:

```
; WITH T AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY imei ORDER BY datetime) RN
    FROM tblName)
SELECT T1.imei, T1.status, T1.datetime [date1], T2.datetime [date2], DATEDIFF(mi, T1.datetime, T2.datetime) [difference], CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(mi, T1.datetime, T2.datetime) > 5 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END -- 'Y' means greater than 5, 'N' less than or equal to 5
FROM T T1 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT imei, RN, datetime FROM T WHERE RN > 1) T2 ON T2.RN-1 = T1.RN AND T1.imei = T2.imei
WHERE T1.Status = 0
```

Comment: i need only those records that have time interval greater then 15 minutes with same imei

Comment: my question is calculate time interval between row1 datetime and row2 datetime then row2 datetime and row3 datetime

Comment: how to store below query result into temporary table

WITH T AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY imei_no ORDER BY vDateTime) RN
    FROM test_observations where imei_no=10000001 and vDateTime >=  @StartDate AND vDateTime <=  @EndDate)
SELECT T1.imei_no, T1.vdin4, T1.vDateTime [date1], T2.vDateTime [date2]
FROM T T1 
JOIN (SELECT imei_no, RN, vDateTime FROM T WHERE RN > 0) T2 ON T2.RN-1 = T1.RN AND T1.imei_no = T2.imei_no
WHERE (T1.vDateTime < DATEADD(mm, 15, T2.vDateTime))
AND T1.vdin4 = 0)

Comment: the above query give me the result in date1 and date2 column then how to get time interval between date1 and date2 value

Comment: just datediff them if you want the interval e.g. add a column in the select statement DATEDIFF(mi, T1.datetime, T2.datetime) [difference] (editing answer to reflect this)